# Finding the local minima with a robot in python

Tags: python

So I have been given this question and I have spent hours trying to solve it but I can't seem to get it right.

Here's the question:

In the number grid below, we will define a local minima as a square with the smallest number out of its four surrounding squares (above, below, to the left and to the right) that are not obstacles.

Program the robot to find and paint a square that is a local minima.

Functions: turnLeft(), turnRight(), forward(), paint(), squareNumber(), obstacleAhead().

paint() will paint the square beneath the robot, squareNumber() checks the number of the square beneath the robot, and obstacleAhead() checks if there is a square in front of the robot.

Also, using lists or defining new functions is not allowed.

The program is tested with multiple grids so I need to make a solution that works for any grid.

I am not sure how to make the robot move in a way that it checks all the squares but also doesn't get stuck. Any help would be appreciated!

[Picture of a grid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/obWiU.png)

Comment: You don't *need* to check all the squares. You just need to find a local minimum. That's a local property, not a global property.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. With the functions they give, the only way to find the local minima is search all the squares until it finds one, and there are multiple grids so I can't just make a solution that works specifically for one of them

Comment: Classic StackOverflow: "spent hours", not a single line of code shared. What did you try? What did you expect to work? What happened instead?

Comment: None of the function definitions or variables are in english so I don't think it would be of much help if I posted it. My idea was to go through each square and check the surrounding ones if possible. If any of them are smaller than the original square, it goes to the next square and tries again. My problem is that it keeps getting stuck and I am not sure what to do to avoid that.

Comment: Is "a local minima" really the original text?

Comment: Isn't getting stuck the *goal* here?

Answer (score -1):

You think you need to try every square, but you don't.

If a square isn't a local minimum, that means there's an adjacent square with a lower number. If *that* square isn't a local minimum, there's an adjacent square with a lower number. If *that* square isn't a local minimum, etc.

If you follow a path of decreasing numbers, that path can't go on forever, because the grid is finite. Eventually, the path has to end, on a local minimum.